# I want to uninstall Ubuntu completely and install Windows 8.1, but everything I've tried hasn't worked

Tags: windows, uninstall

I've bought a Windows 8.1 key with the intention of uninstalling Ubuntu 14.04 and installing Windows 8.1. I don't have a recovery disk, but I do have a USB handy that I can run something from... I'm very new to Linux so no suggestion is too simple!
I wouldn't mind a dual boot but I'd prefer a full wipe - any information required feel free to ask.
Thanks.

Comment: You didn't give us anything specific, so this is the best we can do.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly.. you need to contact Microsoft support to get an installation medium if you don't have a Windows system that you can use to use the official MS download tool.

You can then easily delete the Ubuntu installation during the Windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

Providing there isn't anything that you want to back up on Ubuntu or the USB drive that you will use for the install, do the following: On another Windows PC, go to the Microsoft [Upgrading Windows with only a product key](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only) website and download and run the EXE file for Windows 8.1. When given the option click `Install Windows by creating media` and select the option to create USB media and select your USB (it will be wiped). After this has completed, boot your Ubuntu PC from the USB. How you do this varies depending on your computer make and model so Google is your friend here. In general, press F2, F12 or ESC to launch the boot menu and then select the USB stick with the arrow keys and press Enter. The PC should boot in to the Windows 8.1 install wizard. Go through the wizard and when you get to the partitioning stage, providing you want to completely erase the contents of your hard disk, remove all of the existing partitions and click `Next`. After the install finishes, the PC should boot in to Windows 8.1. Congratulations!

**Please note that your hard disk and the USB that you used to install Windows WILL BE WIPED. I am not responsible for any damage that you do to your PC!**